# Canvas - Increase animation speed without jolts

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

How can I increase the speed of my canvas animation and still get a smoothly moving object?

In my example a boy is moving from the top to the bottom of the canvas. The movement seems to jolt, the bigger the y-step is. How can I avoid the jolts and still have a fast movement to the bottom?

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/job6uy42/3/)**

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();

(function animloop() {
    requestAnimFrame(animloop);
    redraw();
})();


function redraw() {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(20, y, 90, 90);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fill();
    y += 5;

}
```

Comment: by incrementing the y position in the requestAnimationFrame callback directly, your animation will appear differently on different devices based on the frame rate, instead you should use time-based animation (http://blog.sklambert.com/using-time-based-animation-implement/) and flickering may be caused because you are clearing the entire canvas and then redrawing your scene, you could try doing double buffering by flipping 2 canvas elements (http://blog.bob.sh/2012/12/double-buffering-with-html-5-canvas.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can increase the speed your canvas animation and still get a smoothly moving object by reducing the distance travelled per frame and increasing the frame rate.

RequestAnimationFrame is a performant way of animating at a reasonable framerate given your hardware but it fixes the framerate.

You can have more control over the framerate using setInterval or setTimeout instead, which accepts a second integer argument that determines milliseconds till next callback (i.e. framerate).

```
setInterval(function () {
  redraw();
}, 2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uq14c6bu/2/